# Xamarin stepping over an awaitable method

Tags: debugging, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android, async-await

In a WPF app stepping over (F10) an awaitable method takes you to the next line, But in a xamarin android project it does not behave that way (it's as if I pressed F5) and I'm obliged to put a break point on the next line in order to debug properly -It's a pain in the ass-.

```
 async Task SomeMethod()
 {
     await Task.Delay(1000); <--------- Stepping over this line leaves the function.
     int x = 1; <--------- I have to add a breakpoint here.
 }
```

Is it a bug or a feature?

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: awkward debugging experience with xamarin is usually a bug. Shift f11 usually crashes the debugger while it used to work until mono 5 came along. If i were you i'd report it at bugzilla.xamarin.com. Hopefully they end up fixing it. Debugging sure is a pita compared to ordinary wpf applications

Comment: It probably a feature of `async` - it simply goes out of method scope for `await` operation, and continues in backgroun. Maybe, you should switch **off** the `Just My Code` checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how `await` operator works. When you `await` a `Task`, code execution will jump out of the current function and yield control to its caller. Then at some point later in time after the awaited `Task` finishes, it will jump back to execute code after the `await` statement.

If you step over an `await`, the debugger will navigate you to the next line of code that is going to be executed. In case of `await` it is most likely not going to be the following line.

Comment: Please try the code in WPF, Windows Forms or Windows Phone, F10 will take you to "int x=1", then try it in Xamarin.Forms or Android it won't.

Comment: @voytasify That is _not_ how await works. Await will execute the method called with the `await` keyword immediately and execute the code inside the method. Only when there are other (usually I/O bound) operations being called in the called method (or its called methods), that await their own result (by also calling a method with `await` or by returning a `Task`), the current thread might be repurposed for some time by the scheduler. Therefore, stepping into an awaited method should always work, as should stepping over one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your method is in asynchronous. Tested mine & it is working from my side. Example below:-

```
  Task.Run(async () =>
      {
        await Task.Delay(1000); 
        int x = 1;
      });
```

or

```
async Task YourMethod
    {
       await Task.Delay(1000); 
       int x = 1;
    }
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? And is it in Xamarin Droid?

Comment: Latest version for Visual Studio for Mac & yes it is Xamarin Droid.

Answer (score 0):

This is, unfortunately, how visual studio debugging currently works.  As the `Task.Delay()` method has been awaited, the programme flow goes back to the method that called `YourMethod()`. If that call was awaited, and the chain of calls to that method where all awaited back and so forth until it reaches the applications context.  E.g. for Xamarin:

e.g.

```
 1 class MyActivity : Activity
 2 {
 3     // This function is called by the Xamarin/Android systems and is not awaited.
 4     // As it is marked as async, any awaited calls within will pause this function,
 5     // and the application will continue with the function that called this function,
 6     // returning to this function when the awaited call finishes.
 7     // This means the UI is not blocked and is responsive to the user.
 8     public async void OnCreate()
 9     {
10         base.OnCreate();
11         await initialiseAsync();  // awaited - so will return to calling function
12                                   // while waiting for operation to complete.
13
14         // Code here will run after initialiseAsync() has finished.
15     }
16     public async Task initialiseAsync()
17     {
18         await YourMethod();  // awaited - so will return to Line 11
19                              // while waiting for operation to complete.
20         
21         // Code here will run after GetNamesAsync() has finished.
22     }
23 }
```

In pure windows applications, Visual Studio knows all about the application's context and knows that the underlying methods (programme lifecycle, window events, screen-redraws etc.) don't need to be debugged (and the source code is inaccessible).  What you are probably seeing is the debugger pause for the 1000ms as there is no code to be debugged.

Xamarin puts an extra layer of code in, with things like the implementation of the base `Activity` class and all of the Android requirements.  Visual Studio doesn't know to skip these and so tries to debug whatever code called the current awaited stack of methods.  This will probably be something like the base `Activity` class's `OnCreate()` method - which you probably don't have access to the code for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug, and has been for many years. You can track progress here and chime in - maybe we can get it fixed!

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5554